# trasseract Unsupported image object

Tags: python

I learning python and I want read a document but ones words are diferent. I use this code,

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

img = cv2.imread('tes_palabra.png')

words = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(words)
```

image used and required is https://ibb.co/KscWbD3

but return Unsupported image object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try somethink like this, using **Image** module from PIL:

```
from PIL import Image 
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract'

img_file = r'tes_palabra.png'
img = Image.open(img_file)
words = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(words)
```